# Control the Message encoding when sending email using EWS API

Tags: email, encoding, utf-8, exchangewebservices, iso-8859-1

I'm using Microsoft EWS (Exchange web services) to send emails to external customers (regarding support calls).

One of our customers is trying to automatically import the email message body to their own support call system (which is JAVA based i think) and they keep getting this exception:

**Unsupported Encoding Exception: iso-8859-10**

so they've asked me to change it to UTF8

If I send them an email from my Outlook (which is a client of the same Exchange) it works fine. It only happens when send via EWS.

Here's my code:

```
 protected void SendEmail2(string recipientsAddresses, string senderAddress, string ccRecipients, string subject, string body, bool CCToSender, bool simulate, Importance messageImportance)
    {
        ExchangeService service = null;
        EmailMessage message = null;

        try
        {
            // initialize a proxy to the exchange web services 
            service = new ExchangeService(MAGMA_EXCHAGE_VERSION);
            service.Url = new Uri(MAGMA_EWS_URI);

            // create the message
            message = new EmailMessage(service);

            // Add recipients
            foreach (string recipientEmail in recipientsAddresses.Split(";".ToCharArray()))
            {
                message.ToRecipients.Add(new EmailAddress(recipientEmail));
            }

            // handle inline images
            body = AddInlineImages(message, body);

            // set everything
            message.From = new EmailAddress(senderAddress);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, body);
            message.Importance = messageImportance;

            // and send
            message.Save();
            FolderId SentFolderForUser = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, senderAddress);
            message.SendAndSaveCopy(SentFolderForUser);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The string that I pass to the "body" is an HTML that contains a:

**meta charset="utf-8"** tag under the header.

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Thanks, Gil.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to recode that and use something like below to set the encoding:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $user, $password, ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2007_SP1);
$msg = new EWSType_MessageType();
$msg->MimeContent = new EWSType_MimeContentType();
$msg->MimeContent->_ = base64_encode("Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    . "From: michael@contoso.com\r\n"
    . "To: amy@contoso.com\r\n"
    . "Subject: nothing\r\n"
    . "Date: Tue, 15 Feb 2011 22:06:21 -0000\r\n"
    . "Message-ID: <{0}>\r\n"
    . "X-Experimental: some value\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . "I have nothing further to say.\r\n");
$msg->MimeContent->CharacterSet = 'UTF-8';
```

additional see this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032977/php-sending-email-with-cyrillic-ukrainian-text/47093524#47093524) as it seamed to be similar.

Note: Here is a good [starting point regarding the content-type encoding](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails) option. You also might wish to check the official Microsoft howto [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh545614%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).